# when to use viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidload

I am new to both iOS development and programming in general. I need some clarification as to what sort of things should be declared in the `viewDidLoad` function of a `UIViewController` subclass

Thanks

Comment: Please check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad)  for more information.

Comment: Or the [Resource Management in View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW36).

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly understand what viewDidLoad does, you should understand the View Controller Lifecycle. The best point to start is reading the Apple Documentation, e.g. the learning guides for developing iOS Apps: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html

Answer (score 0):

Everything you write inside the `viewDidLoad` function will run the the View(which can be TableView, ViewController & more..) is loaded.

**For example**, if you got a label called 'label' and you want to set it's by the code so you type:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.text = String("any text here")
}
```

and then the text of the label will change when the View will load.

Answer (score 0):

Declare elements that don't need to be refreshed or recreated when the view reloads. For instance, viewDidLoad is called only when it is created while viewDidAppear will be called every time the view is shown.

Read up on some apple docs.